# how to convert UTC date/time into MDT and military time for react application?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I am trying to convert UTC into MDT (mountain time) format. I am not sure which moment format require to convert date time into MDT. i tried moment.fromOADate(41493) but not working. TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mountain time is GMT -6, so you should be able to use moment().utcOffset(-6)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_Time_Zone

https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/09-utc-offset/

Comment: See Emily's answer. Accounting for daylight saving is the right way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about accounting for daylight savings time and can't just subtract 6 hours, you might also look into the [moment.js timezone library](https://momentjs.com/timezone).

You could say something like is described [here](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/parse/) and do `var zone = moment.tz.zone('America/Chihuahua')` (this is mountain time), then get your time offset with `zone.parse(utcTimestamp)`

Comment: Note that `America/Chihuahua` is not the same as Mountain Time in the United States, because it changes to/from daylight savings on different dates.  For the US, you may want `America/Denver`... but most of Arizona (`America/Phoenix`) is also on Mountain Time except that it doesn't use daylight time at all... so just saying "Mountain Time" is really not so simple.  Time zones are hard.